# Saber que picturebox esta en "x" posición c# VisualStudio

Tags: c#, picturebox

estoy haciendo un programa en el que permite llevar las estadisticas de un torneo, el logo del equipo se carga en unas picturebox, ahora mismo estoy en la parte de presentar visualmente el avanze del torneo, pero no se de que manera solucionar que al avanzar a la segunda ronda detecte cuales son los picturebox que estan disponibles para pasar a la siguiente,

Imagen de referencia, no se como saber cuales son los picturebox de la ultima ronda pues al disputarse esta uno de los dos picturebox debe de pasar a la siguiente.

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No queda para nada claro cual es tu problema, por lo que interpreto, siempre tenes 2 `picturebox`, lo que cambias es la imagen, no los `picturebox`, o me equivoco?

Comment: trate de explicarme lo mejor posible, disculpa, pero hay te va, tengo un numero de picturebox que dependen del numero de equipos que van a jugar, cuando se le da al botón ">" nos permite agregar los goles de los equipos, pasa a la siguiente fase aquel que tenga mas puntos,  por lo cual el picturebox ganador cambia de posición a la siguiente fase. Ahora, ¿como  puedo obtener el nombre de los picturebox o  "equipos" que se enfrentaran en esa ronda? porque uno de estos cambiara de posicion pero no se como reconocer que equipos son los que están disponibles a pasar a la siguiente fase

Answer (score 0):

El control `Picturebox` tiene una propiedad llamada `Tag`

[Tag Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.5#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Tag)

alli puedes poner informacion adicional que sea util al contexto que estas desarrollando.

Si por ejemplo a un picturebox le asignas al tag `equipo1` podrias luego si es que este equipo tiene que avanzar conocer cual control tiene ese nombre asignado y cambialro de posicion

Para buscar cual es el picture podrias ayudarte con linq

```
var pic = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Tag.ToString() == NombreEquipo);

if(pic != null){ 
   pic.Location = ...; //cambias de posicion el pic que concide con el equipo
}
```

Con esto aportas contexto a los controles visuales y los relacionas de alguna forma con datos adicionales.

Comment: Disculpa pero que es lo que realiza "var pic = this.Controls...." ?

Comment: `this` es la instancia del Form, entonces tomas los controles que pones en este, tomando solo los que son picturebox